# I have a commercial rotorcraft student and he wants to get rated in an airplane

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-training, pilots, pilot-certification, cfi

My new student has his commercial rotorcraft. He is working on his ASEL and he already has most of the experience requirements for PPL. Since he is already commercial rated wouldnt he be taking his commercial check ride in an airplane instead of going for his private?

Comment: Are you asking about regulations in the U.S. or another country?  Is your student seeking Commercial privileges or Private privileges in the ASEL?

Comment: U.S. and Commercial, his end goal is airlines. He has over 1,000 hours in a helicopter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your student would be taking his check ride in an **airplane** (the new category of aircraft being added). Adding a Private pilot airplane rating prior to adding a Commercial pilot airplane rating is not a requirement.

Adding an additional category (Airplane) rating to an existing certificate with a different category rating (Rotorcraft) is addressed in [14 CFR Part § 61.63 - Additional aircraft ratings (other than for ratings at the airline transport pilot certification level)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/section-61.63).

Specifically 14 CFR Part 61.63 (b):

> **Additional aircraft category rating**.  A person who applies to add a category rating to a pilot certificate:

> > (1) Must complete the training and have the applicable aeronautical experience.
>
> > (2) Must have a logbook or training record endorsement from an authorized instructor attesting that the person was found competent in the appropriate aeronautical knowledge areas and proficient in the appropriate areas of operation.
>
> > (3) Must pass the practical test.
>
> > (4) Need not take an additional knowledge test, provided the applicant holds an airplane, rotorcraft, powered-lift, weight-shift-control aircraft, powered parachute, or airship rating at that pilot certificate level.

A couple of notes:

- Review page A-12 of the [Commercial Pilot ‒ Airplane
  Airman Certification Standards](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/training_testing/testing/acs/commercial_airplane_acs_change_1.pdf) to see what the required "Tasks" will be for a pilot adding an Airplane Single-engine Land "rating" to and existing Commercial Pilot "certificate" (based on the Commercial Pilot rating currently held);
- Since you did not mention the issue of an instrument rating I'm assuming that is not of interest to you in this question. If it is, then you should review [14 CFR 61.133(b)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61#p-61.133(b)) - Commercial pilot limitations;
- Before your ASEL student flies solo (acting as PIC) he will need a "Flight Review" (14 CFR 61.56) per this [FAA Letter of Interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/faa_migrate/interps/2016/Bennett-Southern_California_Soaring_Academy_2016_Legal_Interpretation.pdf) as well as your endorsement authorizing solo privileges (See [14 CFR 61.31 (d)(2)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61#p-61.31(d))).
- Also, note Endorsement A.72 located on page A-19 from [AC 61-65H](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65h.pdf) - Certification: Pilots and Flight and Ground Instructors.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Miaflyer219 I've added a couple of extra notes to my answer that may be of help to you.

Comment: Basically it would be easier and probably a little less expensive for my student to get his PPL in an airplane  before commercial? Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @Miaflyer219  Perhaps, but you would have to consider the hours your student has already flown in an airplane as solo (PIC) and training hours (non PIC).  Also, you would have to do the training in the "Areas of Operation" - FAR 61.107(b) (ref: 61.63(b). So, I suggest you map out all of the requirements of getting a Private ASEL rating first and then getting a Commercial ASEL rating (both using 61.63).  Then decide based on pricing and/or preference.

Comment: Okay , thank you

Answer (score 1):

He certainly can decide to go straight for the commercial, but he needs to meet the requirements specific to airplanes:

- 50 hours PIC
- 10 hours PIC cross country
- 20 hours training
- 5 hours of instrument training
- 10 hours of training in a complex or TAA airplane
- day and night 2-hour training cross countries
- 300 nm "solo" cross country
- 5 hours night VFR "solo" with 10 landings

Until *all* of this is done and he passes the commercial checkride, he's limited to barely more than student privileges. In particular, he can't carry passengers or log PIC time while receiving instruction. Some likely sticking points:

- he will need to do 5 solo night hours. Since he's not rated in the category, insurance or school policy may be a barrier. Similarly for the long cross country. You can get around this by going along with him as long as you don't actually do any flying or teaching. But then he's essentially paying you to twiddle your thumbs, which eats into the potential cost savings from his point of view and may be pretty boring for you.
- 50 hours is a quite a bit of time to have to fly solo. Remember that training hours don't count as PIC since he won't be rated in the category (though if he pays you to twiddle your thumbs for 10 hours for insurance purposes, those count).
- it's probably cheaper to get the private first. It costs an extra DPE fee but afterwards he can count training hours towards the PIC requirements, instead of those being two separate totals.

So while this is possible, it's probably a better idea for him to get the private as soon as possible and then start working on the commercial.

Comment: @RTO Thanks! I knew there was some bit that wasn't *quite* the same as student privileges, but I couldn't quite remember what part.

Comment: And the 50 hours PIC requirement - the 10 hour PIC XC requirement can count towards that as well. I wanted to verify before assuming.

Comment: @Miaflyer219 If you mean with you tagging along, then yes, but only up to 10 hours count, and only if you are fulfilling the requirements of 61.129(a)(4), and only if you aren't doing any instruction or flying. If he is solo then any solo XC hours count for both PIC XC and PIC with no limit on hours.

Comment: Okay, Thank you